# ckeditor not loading on element generated via ajax on popup dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using custom form and generating form elements with ajax call but textarea is not loaded with ckeditor. this form load on popup dialog. Here is my code:

```
ajax code:

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reg_arz_ajax2.php",
    data: "book="+book_arzyabi,
    dataType : "html",
    success: function(response){

        $('#resp').html(response);
                    ckeditor.replace('fname'); 
        $("#fname").ckeditor();
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        //On error, we alert user
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open");

});
```

php code:

```
    echo '<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="fname" name="fname" rows="10" >test</textarea>';
```

html code:

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../include/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../include/ckeditor/sample.js" ></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form>
 <fieldset>
 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <div id="resp" ></div>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help me for resolve problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the textarea to a CKEditor instance by hand, since replacing by assigning class names is only done once - on page load.

[There are samples on how to convert a textarea to a ckeditor instance](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/replacebycode.html), which is basically just:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id' )
```

so in your case you should add

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'fname' )
```

to the ajax success callback.

Please notice that **Javascript is case sensitive**, so you should write `CKEDITOR` in uppercase. The function call `ckeditor` after the `replace` is also too much. See the examples for official guidelines.